# How to include staticfiles in wsgi django project?

Tags: python, css, django, wsgi

Today I ran into a problem connecting static files to my project.

If I run django app with command: `python manage.py runserver <ip>:<port>`then static files are found. If I run the django app as a wsgi service (`systemctl start myapp`), I get an error that no static files were found.

My project in /home/alevt/health_check. I have next structure of project:

```
---- client
-------- manage.py
-------- my.ini
-------- app
------------ urls.py
------------ settings.py
------------ wsgi.py
-------- health_app
------------ urls.py
------------ static
--------------- scripts
----------------- myscript.js
------------ templates
--------------- index.html
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ ...
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'health_app',
...]
 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'scripts/myscript.js' %}"></script>
```

ERROR

```
Not Found: /static/scripts/myscript.js
```

my.ini

```
[uwsgi]
http = 10.107.14.161:8000
module=app.wsgi:application
chdir = /home/alevt/health_check/client/
wsgi-file = /home/alevt/health_check/client/app/wsgi.py
virtualenv=/home/alevt/health_check/env
single-interpreter = true
enable-threads = true
master = true
```

And my file of service

````
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
 
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'uwsgi --ini /home/alevt/health_check/client/my.ini'
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target```
````

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168308/getting-404-for-all-static-files-during-wsgi-setup-with-django

Comment: have you run cmd : python manage.py collectstatic .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'health_app/static/')
)
```

**my.ini** file:

```
static = /health_app/static
```

Comment: I have added health_app in staticfiles dirs because your static folder inside health_app

Comment: [pid: 34749|app: 0|req: 3/3] 10.78.8.45 () {36 vars in 709 bytes} [Wed Nov 16 13:29:34 2022] GET /health_app/static/scripts/myscript.js
bash[34747]: Not Found: /health_app/static/scripts/myscript.js

Comment: I think you need to add static path in my.ini uwsgi file